# destination view not found error in xPage mobile app

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to create a simple mobile xPage app and am getting the following error when attempting to open a document:

`dojox.mobile.view#preformTransition: destination view not found: null`

I'm using multiple application page controls inside a single page control and have verified no typos in the page name references.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" 
           xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1" selectedPageName="homePage">
    <!-- Start of Home Page -->
    <xe:appPage id="appPage0" pageName="homePage">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading2" label="MOM Directory"></xe:djxmHeading>

        <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList1">
            <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem1" label="Everyone"
                moveTo="#viewPageEveryone">
            </xe:djxmLineItem>
            <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem2" label="Lakeville"
                moveTo="#viewPageLakeville">
            </xe:djxmLineItem>
            <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem3" label="Minneapolis"></xe:djxmLineItem>
            <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem4" label="Northfield"></xe:djxmLineItem>
        </xe:djxmRoundRectList>

        </xe:appPage>
    <!--  End of Home Page -->
    <!-- Start of view Page Everyone -->
    <xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="viewPageEveryone" resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="Everyone View"></xe:djxmHeading>
        <xe:dataView id="dataView1" openDocAsReadonly="true"
            rows="9" pageName="#documentPage">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:link escape="true" id="link1" xp:key="pagerBottomLeft"
                    text="More">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                        <xp:this.script>
                            <xe:addRows for="dataView1" disableId="link1">
                            </xe:addRows>
                        </xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:link>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xe:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="ALL">
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xe:this.data>
            <xe:this.summaryColumn>
                <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="last_name"></xe:viewSummaryColumn>
            </xe:this.summaryColumn>
        </xe:dataView>
    </xe:appPage>
    <!-- End of view Page everyone -->

    <!-- Start of view Page Lakeville -->
    <xe:appPage id="appPage3" pageName="viewPageLakeville" resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading3" label="Lakeville View"></xe:djxmHeading>
        <xe:dataView id="dataView2" openDocAsReadonly="true"
            rows="9" pageName="#documentPage">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:link escape="true" id="link2" xp:key="pagerBottomLeft"
                    text="More">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                        <xp:this.script>
                            <xe:addRows for="dataView2" disableId="link2">
                            </xe:addRows>
                        </xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:link>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xe:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="LKVL">
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xe:this.data>
            <xe:this.summaryColumn>
                <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="last_name"></xe:viewSummaryColumn>
            </xe:this.summaryColumn>
        </xe:dataView>
    </xe:appPage>
    <!-- End of view Page Lakeville -->

    <!-- Start of Document Page -->
    <xe:appPage id="appPage2" pageName="documentPage" resetContent="true" preload="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="documentPageHeading" back="Back" label="Document" moveTo="homePage"></xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"
                    formName="frmBB">
                </xp:dominoDocument>
            </xp:this.data>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:appPage>
    <!-- End of Document Page -->

</xe:singlePageApp>
```

I've searched a lot and found several references to this error but nothing so far that helps.  I'm running a 8.5.3 FP3 server with UP1 and Notes 9 Beta Designer client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you move to the Everyone and Lakeville pages with no problems? Do you have the xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix property set in xsp.properties?

Comment: Yes and Yes.  Movement between the view pages works fine.  Just opening the document fails.  xsp properties setting is:  xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix=mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this out on 9.0 and your markup Shean works fine. I had to point it to different data sources but all in all it works. 
This is what I used...

```
<xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1" selectedPageName="homePage">
<!-- Start of Home Page -->
<xe:appPage id="appPage0" pageName="homePage">
    <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading2" label="MOM Directory"></xe:djxmHeading>

    <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList1">
        <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem1" label="Everyone"
            moveTo="#viewPageEveryone">
        </xe:djxmLineItem>
        <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem2" label="Lakeville">
        </xe:djxmLineItem>
        <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem3" label="Minneapolis"></xe:djxmLineItem>
        <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem4" label="Northfield"></xe:djxmLineItem>
    </xe:djxmRoundRectList>

    </xe:appPage>
<!--  End of Home Page -->
<!-- Start of view Page Everyone -->
<xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="viewPageEveryone" resetContent="true">
    <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="Everyone View"></xe:djxmHeading>
    <xe:dataView id="dataView1" openDocAsReadonly="true"
        rows="9" pageName="#documentPage">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:link escape="true" id="link1" xp:key="pagerBottomLeft"
                text="More">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script>
                        <xe:addRows for="dataView1" disableId="link1">
                        </xe:addRows>
                    </xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:link>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xe:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="v01">
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xe:this.data>
        <xe:this.summaryColumn>
            <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="subject"></xe:viewSummaryColumn>
        </xe:this.summaryColumn>
    </xe:dataView>
</xe:appPage>
<!-- End of view Page everyone -->

<!-- Start of view Page Lakeville -->
<xe:appPage id="appPage3" pageName="viewPageLakeville" resetContent="true">
    <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading3" label="Lakeville View"></xe:djxmHeading>
    <xe:dataView id="dataView2" openDocAsReadonly="true"
        rows="9" pageName="#documentPage">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:link escape="true" id="link2" xp:key="pagerBottomLeft"
                text="More">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script>
                        <xe:addRows for="dataView2" disableId="link2">
                        </xe:addRows>
                    </xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:link>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xe:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="LKVL">
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xe:this.data>
        <xe:this.summaryColumn>
            <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="last_name"></xe:viewSummaryColumn>
        </xe:this.summaryColumn>
    </xe:dataView>
</xe:appPage>
<!-- End of view Page Lakeville -->

<!-- Start of Document Page -->
<xe:appPage id="appPage2" pageName="documentPage"
    resetContent="true" preload="true">
    <xe:djxmHeading id="documentPageHeading" back="Back"
        label="Document" moveTo="homePage">
    </xe:djxmHeading>
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="f01">
            </xp:dominoDocument>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xe:formTable id="formTable1">
            <xe:formRow id="formRow1" label="Subject: ">
                <xp:inputText id="inputText1"
                    value="#{document1.subject}">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xe:formRow>
        </xe:formTable>

    </xp:panel>
</xe:appPage>
<!-- End of Document Page -->
```

Maybe there is something else going on with the app itself that is spoiling things for you.
You don't have your app set to a specific Dojo version? Or any other restriction like that?

Comment: I don't have anything set in the Dojo version section of xsp properties.  Is is possible something is wrong with the dojo version installed on my server?  I moved my data and design elements to a brand new NSF and have the same error when testing in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe DM me on twitter and we'll work out how to get a sample app to me

Comment: Turns out the answer was that I had not matched the page prefix xsp property to my xpage names.  The property xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix=mobile means that all my mobile xpages need to be named starting with "mobile".  I had missed this subtle point.  Paul Hannon discovered this for me after looking at my NSF.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. That was exactly what I was asking for in my first comment to you :-)

Comment: Yes you did Per. My mistake. I had set the prefix...just incorrectly.  Forgot the relationship between the prefix and xpage name.   Thanks for the suggestion.